# Restriction to subalgebra preserves semi-simplicity of modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $\mathcal A$ be an associative unital algebra over $\mathbb C$.
Let $\mathcal B$ be a subalgebra of $\mathcal A$ and let $V$ be an irreducible $\mathcal A$-module.

If we look at $V$ as a $\mathcal B$-module, must it be a direct sum of irreducible $\mathcal B$-modules?

If it does not hold generally, are there any conditions (on $V$, $\mathcal A$?) that make it work?

Comment: It does not hold generally. For example, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$-module, but not semisimple as a $B$-module, where $B$ is the subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ generated by a nontrivial nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally false, and it is unlikely there are any conditions you can write down to make it work. Along the lines of Darij's comment, you can take the algebra $\mathcal{A}=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and the irreducible module $V=\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the subalgebra of upper triangular matrices. Then, the subspace spanned by the vector $(1,0,\ldots,0)^t$ is a $\mathcal{B}$-submodule, but there is no $\mathcal{B}$-module compliment in $V$ (it is an easy exercise to verify this in the $n=2$ case).

To see that you aren't going to find conditions to make this work, note that the nicest algebras are the semi-simple ones which, by Wedderburn's theorem, are isomorphic to direct sums of matrix algebras. In this case, you can adapt the example above.